# Let $\mathcal F$ be a family such that $A\in\mathcal F$, for some set $A$. Then $\cap\mathcal F\subseteq\cup\mathcal F$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $\mathcal F$ be a family such that $A\in\mathcal F$, for some set $A$. Then $\;\cap\mathcal F\subseteq\cup\mathcal F$.

I didn't understand operations using families very well and I'm not sure how to start this question.

**Edit:** $\;\cap\mathcal F\subseteq\cup\mathcal F\;$ means for any $\;x,\;x\!\in\cap\mathcal F\!\implies\!x\!\in\cup\mathcal F$

**Edit2:** Here is the question on my textbook.

[image: It says the same thing as the post tittle but in portuguese]

**Edit3:** Here it is how my textbook defines family

[image]

For example ,

[image]

Comment: What does $\cap F \subseteq \cup F$ mean? Can you translate that into a simpler statement that doesn't involve the $\subseteq$ symbol?

Comment: Probably means "the intersection of all sets belonging to $F$ is contained in the union of all sets belonging to $F$". Since $A\in F$, we know $F\not=\varnothing$, so it makes sense to intersect over $F$.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow I am aware of what it means. I am attempting to socratically assist OP so that they can understand what needs to be done without being excessively spoonfed.

Comment: Yeah I figured I'd just leave that comment anyway to assist readers who are unfamiliar with the notation.

Comment: But I'm slightly confused here. At least in words, if $x \in \cap F$, then $x$ belongs to *all* the $F$ and hence at least one of the $F$, which means that $x \in \cup F$. This must be a matter of definitions, which is why I'm requesting you to add in the definition of $\cap F$ and $\cup F$ which has been given to you. I'm confused because while this line of reasoning is apparently obvious, I need to write it down in a way so that you would understand it, which I cannot do without knowing how you usually write such proofs.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon the only other thing that was given about this is F : set (set U). But from what I got about families ⋂ is intersection and ⋃ is union

Comment: @EvertonRoberto I am still confused, unfortunately. I may need to look at your textbook to see how this can be phrased. I hope your textbook  is online.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I've decided to up vote the question. I'll continue looking at it.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I have updated the post that now contains the question, and the definitions of family

Comment: @EvertonRoberto Ok, now we shall see! Right, so we must prove that $x \in \cap F$ implies $x \in \cup F$ (by the definition of $\subset$). We will assume that $x\in \cap F$ is true. Now, if $x \in \cap F$, then $\forall A \in F, x \in A$. Now, $\exists A \in F$ is true(this is given to us). Therefore, combining this with the previous definition, we know that $\exists A \in F , x \in A$. But from the definition of $\cup F$, we know that $x\in \cup F$ must be true. This was in words : if you are studying logic, you should try to do this using only symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the requirement that $A\in\mathcal F$ for some $A$ is the same as saying that that $\mathcal F$ is not empty. This is there to ensure that $\bigcap \mathcal F$ is a set. Indeed, $\bigcap \emptyset$ is not an object of our theory, since
$$
x\in\bigcap\emptyset \iff \forall y\in\emptyset (x\in y)\iff \forall y(y\in\emptyset \to x\in y)
$$
Since the antecedent is false, the rightmost implication is true for any $x$. So, $\bigcap \emptyset$ would have every set as an element, which is nonsense by Russell's Paradox.

---

To show that $\bigcap \mathcal F\subset \bigcup\mathcal F$, fix $x\in\bigcap \mathcal F$. This means that $\forall X\in F(x\in X)$. In particular, $x\in A$ for our distinguished $A$. Now, $x\in \bigcup\mathcal F$ means exactly that $x\in X$ *for some $X\in\mathcal F$*. But $A$ is one such set. So, since $x\in A$, we infer that $x\in\bigcup\mathcal F$.

Since $x\in \bigcap\mathcal F$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $\bigcap \mathcal F\subset\bigcup\mathcal F$.